# TAILS - GUI v0.12 does not connect to the daemon (monerod) that is already running

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

GUI v0.12 does not connect to the daemon (monerod) that is already running. That is, when I launch the GUI via `./monero-wallet-gui`, it does not connect to the daemon that is running in a separate terminal. This used to work with GUI v0.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular issue should be resolved GUI v0.13.

<s>This issue is currently [being investigated](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/issues/1291). There is, fortunately, a quick and easy workaround, which is starting GUI v0.12 with `./start-gui.sh`. That is:</s>

1. Browse to the directory `monero-wallet-gui` is located.
2. Open a new terminal.
3. Execute -> `./start-gui.sh`

It should now connect to the daemon (monerod) that is already running in a separate terminal.